Shouldn't `git stash push` followed immediately by `git stash pop` be a no-op?
My git status was in this situation when I accidentally ran git stash push:
>git status
Changes to be committed:
    modified:   m.txt
    new file:   p.txt
    deleted:    h.txt
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   c.txt

>git stash push
Saved working directory and index state WIP on main

>git status
nothing to commit, working tree clean

I expected git stash pop to undo the accidental command and revert to the previous state, but instead I ended up like this:
>git stash pop
Changes to be committed:
    new file:   p.txt
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   c.txt
    modified:   m.txt
    deleted:    h.txt
Dropped refs/stash@{0}


Am I right to think that git add m.txt h.txt will get me back to the original situation?

Is it expected that I have to re-add m.txt and h.txt after a push/pop, or is this a bug in git?



As far as I understand it, it may change the staging area (and ignore files unknown to git) but it should revert the working directory back to the original. From the docs (emphasis mine): "Remove a single stashed state from the stash list and apply it on top of the current working tree state, i.e., do the inverse operation of git stash push. The working directory must match the index."

I wouldn’t expect the porcelain tools to obey nice algebraic invariants, given its reputation.
